# Not able to display selected multiple items on toast where the Checkbox is Checked

Tags: android, checkbox

I am able to load data from database into my custom ListView, but not able to display the item(relevant, courseName to be precise) when the checkbox is checked(multiple checkboxes can be checked) on toast when I press button.

Here is my Adapter code:

```
    public class CourseSelectionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CourseDisplay>{


    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    int layoutResourceId;
    public static List<CourseDisplay> mDataSource;
    public static int checkBoxCounter;


    public CourseSelectionAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<CourseDisplay> items) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, items);

        mContext = context;
        mDataSource = items;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        checkBoxCounter = 0;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataSource.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CourseDisplay getItem(int position) {
        return mDataSource.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //4
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get view for row item
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = null;
        CourseDisplay courseDisplay = getCourse(position);
// 1
        if (row == null) {

            // 2
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_layout, parent, false);

            // 3
            holder = new ViewHolder();


            holder.courseCodeTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.course_id_display);
            holder.courseNameTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.course_name_display);
            holder.courseSelectedCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.course_selection_checkbox);

            holder.courseCodeTextView.setText(courseDisplay.getCourseCode());
            holder.courseNameTextView.setText(courseDisplay.getCourseName());

            holder.courseSelectedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked){
                        checkBoxCounter++;
                        getCourse((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).getCourseSelected();

                    }else {
                        checkBoxCounter--;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Count is: "+ checkBoxCounter);
                }
            });
            // 4
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // 5
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

            // 6
        holder.courseSelectedCheckBox.setTag(position);
        holder.courseSelectedCheckBox.setChecked(courseDisplay.getCourseSelected());

        return row;
    }

    private static final class ViewHolder {
        public TextView courseCodeTextView;
        public TextView courseNameTextView;
        public CheckBox courseSelectedCheckBox;
    }

    CourseDisplay getCourse(int position) {
        return ((CourseDisplay) getItem(position));
    }

    List<CourseDisplay> getBox() {
        List<CourseDisplay> box = new ArrayList<CourseDisplay>();
        for (CourseDisplay p : mDataSource) {
            if (p.getCourseSelected())
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }

}//end class
```

Here is my CourseDisplay code:

```
    package com.example.android.shustudenthelper;

import static android.R.attr.checked;   

public class CourseDisplay{
    private String courseCode;
    private String courseName;
    private boolean courseSelected;

    public CourseDisplay(String courseCode, String courseName, boolean courseSelected) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseSelected = courseSelected;
    }

    public String getCourseCode() {
        return courseCode;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public boolean getCourseSelected(){
        return courseSelected;
    }   

}//end class
```

Here is my database method that gets data from Database:

```
public List<CourseDisplay> getAllCoursesForRegistration() {
    List<CourseDisplay> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    openDataBase();
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(TABLE_COURSES, new String[] {COLUMN_COURSE_CODE,COLUMN_COURSE_NAME,COLUMN_COURSE_SELECTED,COLUMN_COURSE_SELECTED }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String courseCode = mCursor.getString(0);
            String courseName = mCursor.getString(1);
            boolean courseSelected = Boolean.parseBoolean(mCursor.getString(2));
            courses.add(new CourseDisplay(courseCode, courseName,courseSelected));
        }while(mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mCursor.close();
    close();//close Database
    return courses;
}//end method
```

Here is my main activity:

```
    public class CourseSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Button confirm_Button;

    public List<String> labels;
    private static CheckBox saveCourseCheckBox;
    public int checkAccumulator = 0;
    private ListView myListView;
    CourseSelectionAdapter newAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_selection);

        DatabaseOpenHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

        try {
            // check if database exists in app path, if not copy it from assets
            myDbHelper.create();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            // open the database
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }

        //Display in ListView
        populateListView();
        // close the database
        myDbHelper.close();

        onClickConfirmButtonListener();

    }//end OnCreate

    private void populateListView(){

        DatabaseOpenHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);//New Object of Database


        List<CourseDisplay> courseDisplay_data = new ArrayList<CourseDisplay>();

        courseDisplay_data = myDbHelper.getAllCoursesForRegistration();

        newAdapter = new CourseSelectionAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_listview_layout,courseDisplay_data);

        myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_courses);
        myListView.setChoiceMode(2);
        myListView.setAdapter(newAdapter);

        }

    public void onClickConfirmButtonListener() {

        confirm_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.course_register_button);

        confirm_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!(checkBoxCounter < 1) && checkBoxCounter <= 4) {
                    showResult();//Show the courses selected.
                Toast.makeText(CourseSelectionActivity.this, "You are directed to Notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.android.shustudenthelper.NotificationSetupActivity");
                startActivity(intent);}
                else if (checkBoxCounter > 4){
                    Toast.makeText(CourseSelectionActivity.this, "You cannot select more than 4 courses", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (checkBoxCounter < 1){
                    Toast.makeText(CourseSelectionActivity.this, "You need to select at least one course", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showResult() {
        String result = "Selected Courses are :";

        for (CourseDisplay p : newAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.getCourseSelected()){
                result += "\n" + p.getCourseName();

            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}//end class
```

Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a setter method in CourseDisplay class

```
public boolean setCourseSelected(boolean value){
    this.courseSelected = value;
}
```

In CourseSelectionAdapter class, when a checkbox is click, set the value of the checkbox with the method above

```
holder.courseSelectedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked){
            checkBoxCounter++;
            courseDisplay.setCourseSelected(isChecked);

        }else {
            checkBoxCounter--;
        }
        System.out.println("Count is: "+ checkBoxCounter);
    }
});
```

Finally, change showResult() like this

```
public void showResult() {
    String result = "Selected Courses are :";

    for (CourseDisplay p : courseDisplay_data) {
        if (p.getCourseSelected()){
            result += "\n" + p.getCourseName();
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I have made that change. Thanks for that. But that doesn't solve my actual issue. I believe that it has to do something with the showResult() method is where I display the selected courses on toast.

Comment: can you check what this line will return newAdapter.getBox().size(); to see if you are getting any data back.

Comment: Glad you asked me that. When I tested it..it is returning 0. So has it got something to do with getBox() method?

Comment: Yes, if it is returning 0 then your list is empty with no CourseDisplay object in it so you can't display any data in the Toast.

Comment: Could you guide me where I have gone wrong in getting CourseDisplay object in getBox() method..may be something wrong in the code..

Comment: This works fine now. Thanks for your time on this. Appreciate your effort. Basically I am missing to set the value to true when the checkbox is checked right?